# How to store Apache Sling content in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, sling, jackrabbit-oak

I am new to Java and Apache Sling as well. I've been trying to link Sling with MongoDB and these are what I've done so far:

1. I configured `NoSQL MongoDB Resource Provider` in Sling console:

[image: NoSQL config]

2. Then the `Oak Document Node Store Service`:

[image: Oak config]

3. And finally I ran `java -Dsling.run.modes=oak_mongo -jar org.apache
   .sling.launchpad-9.jar -c sling -f -` to run the sling launchpad in mongodb mode. This was the results:

[image: Command Prompt]

As a result, a database named "sling" was created in MongoDB which I could see  via Robo-3T (a MongoDB management tool):

[image: MongoDB]

After creating some content through my maven application using the below plugin and deploying it on Sling, I was able to see my newly created nodes and resources in the Sling browser (http://localhost:8080/bin/browser.html):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Sling-Nodetypes>
                        SLING-INF/nodetypes/nodetypes.cnd
                    </Sling-Nodetypes>
                    <Sling-Initial-Content>
                        SLING-INF/scripts;overwrite:=true;uninstall:=true;path:=/apps/test1/nodes,
                        SLING-INF/content;overwrite:=true;uninstall:=true;path:=/content/test1
                    </Sling-Initial-Content>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However, I need to to store everything inside the MongoDB database but currently, nothing stored in the database. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to start the Sling Launchpad with the following argument: `-Dsling.run.modes=oak-mongo` . This will ensure that the Oak is configured to use Mongo. You must remove the `sling` directory, otherwise the run modes will not be changes.

---

What you've done with your attempts is to:

1. add a new resource provider which shadows the current one at the repository root. I am not sure of the actual effects, it is probably rejected - please see the sling error log
2. configure a new Oak NodeStoreService which uses Mongo - but it's probably not picked up since there is already a NodeStoreService in action - Sling requires one to start up.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert, removing the sling directory did the trick :)

Comment: With the Sling Starter 12 snapshot - is there a still a way to switch via a run mode? That is, make a feature archive containing both the tar and mongo datastores and switch via the command line?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStörr - I don't think so. You could try have multiple FAR files, or maybe a FAR file with all bundles and then two small feature files which just contain the required OSGi configs.